# Links between documentation (Sphinx) and Django app

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I have documentation for users of an application written in Sphinx. Up to now the documentation are static HTML pages which can be accessed by the user.

I want to create link between the app and the documentation. Of course I could do it with fragile `<a href="..">` links, but I would like to use `reverse()` to link from Sphinx to a view and a sphinx-reference to link from the app to the documentation.

I could replace sphinx if there is a better approach. But I want to keep the documentation in revision control in the file system (not in the database).

Any hints?

Comment: [`sphinx.ext.intersphinx`](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/latest/ext/intersphinx.html) may give you some hint.

Answer (score 1):

Check out readthedocs.org.  You can either have them host your documentation--or you can download their app from GitHub and integrate it into yours.  (https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org)

Comment: This is a commercial django application and the documentation should be served from the same (intranet) host. Links written by hand (<a href="...") are fragile. Intersphinx links seem to be a good solution. My app needs to create a python-inv.txt file.....

Comment: I believe the source code for readthedocs.org is available at the link in my previous message--so you could run in on your intranet.